# Need Help in calling NPAPI plugin methods from javascript

Tags: plugins, npapi

I am writing one plugin using NPAPI. I was looking for simple example which shows javascript calling NPAPI plugin methods. Please advice

Edit : Example should show all required method implementation in PLugin and how it exposes the NSobject to browser. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see question [Pass url from java script to NPAPI plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986390/pass-url-from-java-script-to-npapi-plugin/6987134#6987134)

javascript example:

```
 var plugin = document.getElementById("objecttagid");
 // function call
 plugin.someMethod(3,4);
 var someReturnVal = plugin.someOtherMethod(4,5);
```

Given what you aparently know, I would *really really really* strongly advise you to look at [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org); it makes writing NPAPI plugins much easier and they work as ActiveX controls as well.

Comment: Thanks Taxilian for the answer , I will check for fireBreath as well but before that i was looking for PLugin example that shows NPObject wrapping and all required method implemetation

Comment: By the way thanks for wonderful article on NPAPI plugin .. only missing part is source code example . I would really appreciate if you could provide me any simple example for Scripting in Plugin .. Thanks in advance

Comment: All the sample code you could hope for is in FireBreath; if you look at Part 4 of the article there are video tutorials walking through the FireBreath NPAPI source code.

Comment: Can i refer those video tutorials for NAPI without FireBreath , i am not using FireBreath ... right now we don't have plans for that but we would like to use in future .. thanks

Comment: the video tutorials are specific to FireBreath, but FireBreath itself is an excellent example of how all of this works. The video tutorials walk you through FireBreath's NPAPI implementation, which means they show you what files to look at for examples of things.