# Pass url from java script to NPAPI plugin

Tags: javascript, npapi

I need to pass currently browsing url string which I have in my javascript to npapi plugin.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see http://npapi.com/tutorial3

You need to create a NPObject to return to the page; you can then implement a method or property for making the call.

You may want to look at [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org); it simplifies all of this.